# how to set dynamic database values through classes and objects in php5

Tags: php, database, php-5.5

This is my code

```
<?php
    class Connection
        {
            function __construct()
                {
                    if(isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']))
                        {
                            switch($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])
                                {
                                    case 'www.hashstar.com':
                                    $this->default = $this->dev;
                                    break;

                                    case 'www.hashstar.in':
                                    $this->default = $this->prod;
                                    break;
                                }
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            $this->default = $this->dev;
                        }
                }

                public $dev = array(
                                        'host' => 'localhost',
                                        'login' => 'root',
                                        'password' => '',
                                        'database' => 'dbname',
                                     );

                public $prod = array(
                                        'host' => 'localhost',
                                        'login' => 'db_admin',
                                        'password' => 'Admin@.2017',
                                        'database' => 'db_main',
                                    );

            public function establish_connection()
                {
                    $connection = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db);

                    if($connection == TRUE)
                        {
                            return $connection;
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            die("Could Not Establish Connection! ".$connection->error);
                        }
                }
        }
?>
```

The problem with this code is that i have declared here varaibles 1st for offline and 2nd for online as i am using git i have to again and again change the codes before pushing to master branch. I even tried to use the .gitignore feature but it isn't working as well but still i wan to set the variables dynamically according to the server host.

I have tried using the switch case thing but its giving an syntactical error while compiling. Can anyone help mw with this code.

Any helps appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Set your database credentials in a new file that you will then add to .gitignore like so :

```
$dbConfig = array(
  "host" => "localhost",
  ...
)
```

then simply access to your $dbConfig in your Connection class

Comment: can you please provide an example code for this as i am totally new to this thing so i am not able to get u properly whether i have to put this code in class or else where ?

Comment: i have this code in config.php and i am including this in classes.php file

Comment: so you can also include this file where you Connection class is defined and then access your properties with `$dbConfig["host"]` for example.

Comment: can you provide my code in a formatted way ? i can't get you :(

Comment: Without your code from config.php I can't do anything for you

Comment: ohk as you had told i have uodated my code of the post please can u guide me what else i have to do more ?